# Why doesn't Python read my boolean Vacation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement, boolean

I was trying this excercise on Codebat:
Given a day of the week encoded as 0=Sun, 1=Mon, 2=Tue, ...6=Sat, and a boolean indicating if we are on vacation, return a string of the form "7:00" indicating when the alarm clock should ring. On weekdays, the alarm should be "7:00" and on the weekend it should be "10:00". Unless we are on vacation -- then on weekdays it should be "10:00" and weekends it should be "off".

```
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):
  vacation_weekday = vacation and day in range(1,6)
  vacation_weekend = day == 0 and day == 6 and vacation

  if day in range(1,6):
     return  "7:00"
  elif day == 0 or day == 6:
     return  "10:00"
  elif vacation_weekday:
     return "10:00"
  elif vacation_weekend:
     return "off"
```

If i run `print(alarm_clock(1,True))` it returns `"7:00"` instead of `"10:00"`. Can somebody help me ?

Comment: `day == 0 and day == 6` will always be `False`.  What were you intending to do here?

Comment: It return `"7:00"` because that's the first condition you check and it is true. If you want vacation to take precedence, you have to check for it first.

Comment: The logic behind this function is the reason it is not evaluating correctly. If you explain what you are looking to do logically we can rewrite it.

Answer (score 4):

Your first `if` statement checks `if day in range(1, 6)`. If `day` is `1` that will always be true. Since the first condition matched, none of the `elif` conditions are even executed. (Additionally, since you `return` immediately, no other code in the function is executed after that point either.)

You probably want to rearrange the `if` statements so that you check the special cases first, and then the general cases. Alternatively, precompute a `weekend` and/or `weekday` boolean value and then express all the conditions explicitly:

```
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):
    weekday = 1 <= day <= 5
    weekend = not weekday

    if weekend and vacation:
        return "off"
    if weekend and not vacation:
        return "10:00"
    if weekday and vacation:
        return "10:00"
    if weekday and not vacation:
        return "7:00"
```

Or even, using a ternary expression:

```
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):
    weekday = 1 <= day <= 5

    if vacation:
        return "10:00" if weekday else "off"

    return "7:00" if weekday else "10:00"
```

Comment: Even if the body of the `if` clause *weren't* a `return`, none of the `elif` conditions would be checked assuming the `if` was true.

Comment: Truthfully I don't know if its possible to give a real answer to this question unless OP tells us what he is checking for. The logic seems off in the function.

Comment: @EdekiOkoh: I think the intent of the `vacation` option is pretty clearly to override the calculation that would otherwise occur.

Comment: I meant the intent of the function itself. I was confused about what he was trying to return until he made his edits. For example vacation_weekend = day == 0 and day == 6 and vacation is always false. But he was also looking for  elif day == 0 or day == 6:

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you should have rewritten your code to evaluate it properly:

```
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):
   weekday_alarm_clock = "7:00 AM"
   weekend_alarm_clock = "10:00 AM"

   if vacation:
      weekday_alarm_clock = "10:00 AM"
      weekend_alarm_clock = "off"
   if day > 0 and day < 6:
      return weekday_alarm_clock 
   else:
      return weekend_alarm_clock
```

As you can see here, if we are on vacation then we set out weekday alarm clock to 10:00. and turn off the weekend clock. it is not Sunday or Saturday and vacation is not true then we return our normal clock. Else its the weekend and its not vacation and we return our normal weekend alarm clock

Now the output I receive when using `print(alarm_clock(1,True))`is `10:00 AM` as expected

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be a little complex:

```
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):
  weekend = [6,7]
  if day not in weekend and vacation is True:
    return '10:00 AM'
  elif day in weekend and vacation is True:
    return 'off'
  elif day in weekend and vacation is False:
    return '10:00 AM'  
  elif day not in weekend and vacation is False:
    return '7:00 AM'
  else:
    return 'off'

print(alarm_clock(day, vacation))
```